# Combobox stopped working once added to the rest of my code

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I am trying to use a combobox to ask users a reference point that I can use later and I manage to make the Combobox work fine in a test script, but when I add that script to the rest of my code, it stopped working.

Basically:

- I read an excel file into a df
- I get the option by getting the values in the "Event" column
- Open a Combobox and ask which of the "Event" is the "Reference", then close the box
- The plan will be to use that "Reference" point to do a calculation on the other rows

I am currently using part of code found in another post in here but I have an issue.
When I only use the Combobox part of the code (setting Events as ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'...], it works fine. However, when I add that Combobox to the rest of my code, using the list of event generated by the code reading my files, it doesn't work anymore (it seem that it is not reading the class part?).

See below for my code.

I would be really glad to have your help !

Thanks in advance !
Orohena

```
    #Import all library that will be needed
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import filedialog
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk

    #import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    #import numpy as np

    #get result directory
    def popupdir(msg):
        # Set a font
        large_font = ('Verdana', 20)
        #popup window
        popup = tk.Tk()
        #title of the window
        popup.wm_title('User action required')
        #The window, plus the message, font to set the font of message, wrap text, justify to center.
        label = ttk.Label(popup, text=msg, font=large_font, wraplength=500, justify='center')
        #The text will be at the top of the window. padx, pady to make window bigger.
        label.pack(side="top", padx=350, pady=100)
        #Add a button to the popup window, the text of the button is okay. When click, popup window close.
        Button1 = ttk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
        #This would be to modify aspect of button, keep initial settings here
        Button1.pack()
        #Keep window open until user do something.
        popup.mainloop()

    def ComboboxSelection():
        class ComboboxSelectionWindow():
            def __init__(self, master):
                self.master = master
                self.entry_contents = None
                self.labelTop = tk.Label(master, text="Select one of the following")
                self.labelTop.place(x=20, y=10, width=140, height=10)
                self.comboBox_example = ttk.Combobox(master, values=events)
                self.comboBox_example.current(0)
                self.comboBox_example.place(x=20, y=30, width=140, height=25)

                self.okButton = tk.Button(master, text='OK', command=self.callback)
                self.okButton.place(x=20, y=60, width=140, height=25)

            def callback(self):
                self.comboBox_example_contents = self.comboBox_example.get()
                self.master.destroy()

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('Ask a choice !')
        root.geometry('400x400')
        Selection = ComboboxSelectionWindow(root)
        root.mainloop()

        print("Selected interface: ", Selection.comboBox_example_contents)
        return Selection.comboBox_example_contents

    def folderfinder():
        # Call popupdir function to warn users that they'll have to input something
        popupdir('In the next window, you will need to choose the folder containing your results.')
        # To ask the Tk empty box to immediately close
        rootdir = Tk()
        rootdir.withdraw()
        # To ask the user for the directory
        path = tk.filedialog.askdirectory()
        # To close the directory window once the directory has been selected.
        rootdir.update()

        # Change directory to the one with the results
        dir1 = os.chdir(path)
        path1 = os.getcwd() + '/'
        return(path1)


    path1 = folderfinder()

    #get the list of file in the result directory
    file_list = [f for f in os.listdir(path1) if not f.startswith('.')]
    dfeve = pd.read_csv(file_list[0], sep=',')

    dftl = dfeve[['Events']]

    #concatenate all file in one
    for file in file_list:
        nameframe = 'Frames' + file
        nametimes = 'Times' + file
        dffile = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',')
        dffile.rename({'Frames_': nameframe}, axis=1, inplace=True)
        dffile.rename({'Times_': nametimes}, axis=1, inplace=True)
        dftl = dffile.merge(dftl, left_on='Events', right_on='Events')

    events = dftl['Events']
    events = events.tolist()
    print(events)

    print("combo")
    ComboboxSelection()
    print("comboprint")
    print("Tkinter combobox text selected =", ComboboxSelection())
```

It works fine until I click "OK" in the ComboboxSelection, the window close, the code is still running but nothing happen, it does not print anything.

I tried with the class in or out of ComboboxSelection, same result.

Here is the code that is working, I click "OK", the window close, it prints everything it should (out of my code; again I tried with the class in or out of ComboboxSelection and it works in both cases)

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk

    def ComboboxSelection():
        class ComboboxSelectionWindow():
            def __init__(self, master):
                self.master = master
                self.entry_contents = None
                self.labelTop = tk.Label(master, text="Select one of the following")
                self.labelTop.place(x=20, y=10, width=140, height=10)
                self.comboBox_example = ttk.Combobox(master, values=options)
                self.comboBox_example.current(0)
                self.comboBox_example.place(x=20, y=30, width=140, height=25)

                self.okButton = tk.Button(master, text='OK', command=self.callback)
                self.okButton.place(x=20, y=60, width=140, height=25)

            def callback(self):
                """ get the contents of the Entry and exit"""
                self.comboBox_example_contents = self.comboBox_example.get()
                self.master.destroy()

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title('Ask a choice !')
        root.geometry('400x400')
        Selection = ComboboxSelectionWindow(root)
        root.mainloop()

        print("Selected interface: ", Selection.comboBox_example_contents)
        return Selection.comboBox_example_contents

    options = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    print("Tkinter combobox text selected =", ComboboxSelection())
```

Comment: Wait what? Why are You putting a class inside a function definition? I dont think taht should be done

Comment: @Matiiss , honestly I am very new to python so that is probably not a thing... I just thought maybe the class could be taken by my other popup message so I tried. That was out of the function definition in the code I found in another answer. I did try it in or out, and in my test code it works in or out of the function definition. Now, it doesn't mean it something that should or can be done, I'll let experts answer that ^^

Comment: You need to destroy the `rootdir` window inside `folderfinder()` after selecting a folder by changing `rootdir.update()` to `rootdir.destroy()`.  Also you have called `ComboboxSelection()` twice at the end of the script.

Comment: Thank you @acw1668 , it worked perfectly ! I can finally move on to the next bit after a month trying to get that done !

Answer (score 0):

Does this example help You:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Button
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox


values = ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 3', 'Ōption 4']


def get_data():
    print(cb.get())


root = Tk()

cb = Combobox(root, values=values)
cb.pack()
cb.set(values[0])
cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', lambda e: get_data())

root.mainloop()
```

In this case You don't even need a button

And probably the reason You are not getting anything is because none of the functions or classes return anything

One thing You can certainly do is try adding a `print(self.comboBox_example_contents)` after getting the value and before destroying the window

Comment: I did try a simpler version of the combobox before but never managed to get the selection out of the combobox to use it as a variable for some reason. Maybe with that lambda that would work. I will have a look ! Thanks !

Comment: @Orohena no lambda is not necessary here I just wanted to avoid typing an argument to the `get_data()` function because normally `.bind()` also returns an event and I am just passing to the lambda as an argument and not using it anywhere. You could also simply do this: `cb.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', get_data)` and then in the func name: `def get_data(event):` and You don't have to necessarily use that argument. Also with event tho You can get the widget but since You use only one this will fit too